# dispatchgroup executes task in different order in testflight compared to simulator

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

So my goal is to have congruent functionality both on the iOS simulator in Xcode and as well as a physical device on TestFlight. So currently, I have a function that handles refunds in my app. On the simulator the function runs perfectly fine in the order I expect it to, but the print statements execute in the wrong order which I'm assuming is the reason for misbehaviour on TestFlight simulations.

Here is the method:

```
@IBAction func cancelPurchasePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let nameOfEvent = selectedEventName else { return }
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

    
    let alertForCancel = UIAlertController(title: "Cancel Purchase", message: "Are you sure you want to cancel your purchase of a ticket to \(nameOfEvent)? You will receive full reimbursement of what you paid within 5 - 10 days.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    
    let cancelPurchase = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel Purchase", style: .default) { (purchaseCancel) in
        
        self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        self.refundLoading.alpha = 1
        self.refundLoading.startAnimating()
        
        self.makeRefundRequest()
        
       
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)/guests").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("The guests couldn't be fetched.")
                    return
                }
                guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                    print("The user did not bring any guests.")
                    return
                }
                for guest in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let name = guest.documentID
                    group.enter()
                    self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)/guests/\(name)").delete { (error) in
                        guard error == nil else {
                            print("The guests couldn't be deleted.")
                            return
                        }
                        print("Guests deleted with purchase refund.")
                        group.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                
                self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)").delete { (error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("Error trying to delete the purchased event.")
                        return
                    }
                    print("The purchased event was succesfully removed from the database!")
                }
                self.refundLoading.stopAnimating()
                self.refundLoading.alpha = 0
                self.ticketFormButton.isHidden = false
                self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
                self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    alertForCancel.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    alertForCancel.addAction(cancelPurchase)
    present(alertForCancel, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Basically what I have going on is a simple refund request being made to Stripe and a second after I have an `asyncAfter` code block with some database cleanup in it. I have to do the `asyncAfter` or else the refund request gets beat out by the other async tasks by speed.

So I took my knowledge of `DispatchGroups` and decided to implement it since I have an async task in a for loop that I need to be completed before every other task. So I expected this to work fine, despite the order of the print statements being incorrect, but when I ran the exact block of code on my phone via TestFlight, I made a refund and the cell was still showing up in the tableview, meaning the document wasn't deleted from the database properly.

I've been having some terrifying experience recently with `DispatchGroups` and TestFlight and I just honestly hope to fix all this and have these problems come to an end temporarily. Any suggestions on how I can fix this method to prevent incorrect order on TestFlight?

**UPDATE** Decided to use a completion handler instead to do the same functionality:

```
func makeRefundRequest(refundMade: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())) {
    let backendURLForRefund = "https://us-central1-xxxxxx-41f12.cloudfunctions.net/createRefund"
    getStripePaymentIntentID { (paymentid) in
            guard let id = paymentid else { return }
            let url = URL(string: backendURLForRefund)!
            let json: [String: Any] = [
            
                "payment_intent": id
            
            ]
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
                guard let taskError = error?.localizedDescription else { return }
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode == 200,
                      let data = data,
                      let _ = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    self?.showAlert(title: "Refund Request Error", message: "There was an error making the refund request. \(taskError)")
                    refundMade(false)
                    return
                }
            }
        task.resume()
    refundMade(true)
    }
}
```

And then I just slapped this method in the actual refund process method itself:

```
@IBAction func cancelPurchasePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let nameOfEvent = selectedEventName else { return }
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

    
    let alertForCancel = UIAlertController(title: "Cancel Purchase", message: "Are you sure you want to cancel your purchase of a ticket to \(nameOfEvent)? You will receive full reimbursement of what you paid within 5 - 10 days.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    
    let cancelPurchase = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel Purchase", style: .default) { (purchaseCancel) in
        
        self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        self.refundLoading.alpha = 1
        self.refundLoading.startAnimating()
        
        self.makeRefundRequest { (response) in
            if response == false {
                return
            } else {
                let group = DispatchGroup()
                self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)/guests").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("The guests couldn't be fetched.")
                        return
                    }
                    guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                        print("The user did not bring any guests.")
                        return
                    }
                    for guest in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let name = guest.documentID
                        group.enter()
                        self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)/guests/\(name)").delete { (error) in
                            guard error == nil else {
                                print("The guests couldn't be deleted.")
                                return
                            }
                            print("Guests deleted with purchase refund.")
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                group.notify(queue: .main) {
                    
                    self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)").delete { (error) in
                        guard error == nil else {
                            print("Error trying to delete the purchased event.")
                            return
                        }
                        print("The purchased event was succesfully removed from the database!")
                    }
                    self.refundLoading.stopAnimating()
                    self.refundLoading.alpha = 0
                    self.ticketFormButton.isHidden = false
                    self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
                    self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    alertForCancel.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    alertForCancel.addAction(cancelPurchase)
    present(alertForCancel, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This actually does not work fine, yes the refund goes through on Stripe and the database is cleaned up for 3 minutes, but the print statements print in incorrect order and also the document magically reappears in the Firestore database 3 minutes after physically seeing it be deleted, how can I prevent this and make sure they print in correct order and execute in correct order to work properly on TestFlight? Is this an issue in my `DispatchGroup` implementation? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: Can you post the `makeRefundRequest()` function as well? You should simply add a completion handler to it and execute the network task within it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that function it works fine, the only issues is everything after it. @bxod

Comment: What I mean is, you should modify the refund function to give you a completion handler (with a success or failure mechanism) so that you can execute the database tasks after the refund is complete and if it completes (what happens when it fails?). Picking an arbitrary delay of one second is definitely to be avoided for a number of reasons. That is step number one in your serialization of this task.

Comment: Ok i ended up doing that and it works fine, any way I can make sure the print statements are in order correctly? Just so it doesn't backfire in TestFlight. @bxod

Comment: Forgive me but this still doesn't work, it gets deleted out of the database, but reappears like 3 minutes after, this was happening previously with how the function was before as well but it is happening also with the completion handler, can you perhaps explain this? @bxod

Comment: `refundMade(true)` is in the wrong place. Also you need to make sure you have a `leave()` for every `enter()`, so add a `leave()` to your `guard` statement.

Comment: This code only deals with the deletion of documents. If documents are reappearing later then that is an entirely separate problem. Doing a basic search of the entire project where you add or modify documents in this collection is very easy and you should find the culprit relatively quickly.

Comment: Should I place it above the `task.resume()`? Also, where do you see another `enter()` lol? @Don

Comment: After the closing `}` where you call `refundMade(false)`. There's only one `enter()`, but there's no `leave()` if error isn't nil.

Comment: uhh there's no dispatch group in my `makeRefundRequest()` method. I'm so confused. @Don

Comment: I'm referring to the DispatchGroup you are using in `cancelPurchasePressed`. You only call `leave()` if there's not an error. If there ever is an error, `notify` will never be called. However, you should be handling the error there.

Comment: Why aren't you doing all this deleting in a batch operation or transaction? They're atomic, meaning either they all get deleted or none get deleted.

Comment: idek how to do any of that, and as you said, this is a bigger problem since the documents reappear shortly after being deleted from the database completely. I'm just gonna hold my L for now. @bxod

Comment: Never take the L!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important that no matter what you end up doing you should learn how to do everything anyway. I would advise against this approach below but it's what you originally started so let's finish it regardless, so you know how dispatch grouping works. Once you've gotten a handle on this, refine it by replacing the dispatch group with a Firestore transaction or batch operation. The point of the transaction or batch operation is so all of the documents are deleted atomically, meaning they all go or none go. This simplifies things greatly and they are very basic! And the documentation for them is very clear.

The final thing I would suggest is perhaps integrating some recursion, meaning that if something fails it can retry automatically. Recursive functions are also very basic so just learn how to write one in Playground first and then apply it here. Just take it one step at a time and you'll get it down within a day or two. But this is the first step so carefully read what I wrote and understand why I did what I did.

```
func makeRefundRequest(refundMade: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
    getStripePaymentIntentID { (paymentid) in
        guard let id = paymentid,
              let url = URL(string: "https://us-central1-xxxxxx-41f12.cloudfunctions.net/createRefund") else {
            refundMade(false) // always call completion when you exit this function
            return
        }
        let json: [String: Any] = ["payment_intent": id]

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data,
                let _ = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                refundMade(true) // completion: true
            } else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                refundMade(false) // completion: false
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        // do not call the completion of this function here because you just made a network call
        // so call the completion of this function in that call's completion handler
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelPurchasePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let nameOfEvent = selectedEventName,
          let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
              return
    }
    let alertForCancel = UIAlertController(title: "Cancel Purchase", message: "Are you sure you want to cancel your purchase of a ticket to \(nameOfEvent)? You will receive full reimbursement of what you paid within 5 - 10 days.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelPurchase = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel Purchase", style: .default) { (purchaseCancel) in
        // put the UI in a loading state
        self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        self.refundLoading.alpha = 1
        self.refundLoading.startAnimating()
        
        self.makeRefundRequest { (done) in
            if done {
                self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)/guests").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    guard let snapshot = snapshot,
                          !snapshot.isEmpty else {
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return
                    }
                    let group = DispatchGroup() // instatiate the dispatch group outside the loop

                    for doc in snapshot.documents {
                        group.enter() // enter on each loop iteration
                        let name = doc.documentID

                        self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)/guests/\(name)").delete { (error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error)
                            }
                            group.leave() // leave no matter what the outcome, error or not
                                          // what do you do when this document didn't delete?
                                          // by doing all your deleting in a transaction or batch
                                          // you can ensure that they all delete or none delete
                        }
                    }

                    group.notify(queue: .main) { // done with loop, make final network call
                        self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(nameOfEvent)").delete { (error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error)
                            }

                            // put the UI back to normal state
                            self.refundLoading.stopAnimating()
                            self.refundLoading.alpha = 0
                            self.ticketFormButton.isHidden = false
                            self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
                            self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else { // refund was not made, put the UI back into normal state
                self.refundLoading.stopAnimating()
                self.refundLoading.alpha = 0
                self.ticketFormButton.isHidden = false
                self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
                self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    alertForCancel.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    alertForCancel.addAction(cancelPurchase)
    present(alertForCancel, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is great and all, but is this gonna prevent documents from reappearing again? @bxod

Comment: No, you'll have to find the code in your app that is setting or updating that collection. Find all the places that modify that collection and what triggers them. But don't drown yourself in work. Pick one problem and handle that first and then get to the other one.

Comment: that's the only problem right now, the documents reappearing, everything else is okay right now. No point of me learning something that won't provide a solution to be honest. @bxod

Comment: Your code has a number of faults and my answer fixes them. But if that's the attitude you want to take then best of luck!

Comment: I literally tried your code and it crashed with like 100 lines of code in the debug console saying the `stopAnimating()` under the last `else` closure can only be called on the main thread. @bxod

Comment: Then call it on the main thread, it's one line of code. And this is essentially the point I was trying to make: learn the basics before you go any further. That you don't know how to update the UI on the main thread in a background return tells me you should slow down a bit and get the basics down before you just say "oh well" and move on to the next thing. Your code is going to be a giant pile of spaghetti by the time you finish it with this attitude, trust me.

Comment: You weren’t printing the errors in your original code which is why you never saw them. You see them now because my code prints all errors. Just take a couple hours and look over your code. Try to understand why it isn’t working.

Comment: I suspect your other problem of documents reappearing is connected to these errors. And I will assume you aren’t printing errors there either so you’re totally blind as to what is going on behind the scenes. Your code has a bunch of holes in it. You need to start from the beginning and go step by step.

Comment: Yeah i decided to take your advice and use batch writes and the documents are no longer reappearing, sorry for my attitude and stubbornness it was just so frustrating in the moment. Thanks again. @bxod